# Puppet make parameters optional and assign default if null

Tags: puppet

You can pass in parameters into puppet like so.....

```
class foo ($install_version) }

#checkout git branch depending on $install_version 

}
```

How do you set a default value of $install_version if no $install_version is passed in?

Ideally the manifest will checkout the desired git branch, but if a branch is not specified, it will checkout the master branch.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/parameterized_classes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read that page you linked again :-)

Quoting:

> You can also give default values for any parameter in the list:
>
> ```
> class webserver( $vhost_dir = '/etc/httpd/conf.d', $packages = 'httpd' ) {
>   ...
> }
> ```

So, in your case:

```
class foo ($install_version = 'master') }
```